# Letting go of multiple/repeated br tags

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to remove multiple `<br>` tags which are repeated more than 2times, for example:

```
This is text blah blah...
<br><br><br><br><br><br>Another text here
```

Should be:

```
This is text blah blah...
<br><br>Another text here
```

I have this:

```
$str = preg_replace('#(<br\s?/?>)+#', '<br><br>', $str );
```

But this also replace simple `<br>` tags with 2 `br`s, how I could change the regular expression for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one..

```
#(<br\s?/?>){2,}#
```

**[Codepad](http://codepad.org/YltWm1vA)**.

If your `<br>`s include spaces in between then this follow this one -

```
#(<br\s?/?>\s*){2,}#
```

**[Codepad](http://codepad.org/l8CggDUL)**

Comment: Did he want anything like that??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$str = 'This is text blah blah...
<br><br><br><br><br><br>Another text here';

echo preg_replace('#(\s*<br\s*/?>\s*<br\s*/?>\s*)+#', '<br><br>', $str );
```

Output:

```
This is text blah blah...
<br><br>Another text here
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/Gtcjn96B)

Update:
Thanks for @M42 for his point:

```
echo preg_replace('#(\s*<br\s*/?>\s*){2,}#', '<br><br>', $str );
```

Comment: This will replace odd number of `<br>` by 3 `<br>`.

Comment: @M42: did u tested or just imagined this? I hope to show me real test

Comment: @M42: did u see the demo I provided within the answer? ok, post the demo of failed case.

Comment: You have an even number of '<br>` in your test case. Try with an odd number.

Comment: Now, I don't see any difference between your answer and mine!! :)